# Mock Grails Spring Security Logged in User

Tags: testing, grails, spring-security, mocking

Looking for a way to mock spring security in some unit/integration tests.

- Grails: V2.1.0
- Spring Security Core: V1.2.7.3

Controller has the following:

```
// some action
def index(){
   def user = getLoggedInUser()
   render ....
}
...

private getLoggedInUser(){
    return User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
}
```

I tried the following and various other ways but can't see to get it to work:

```
void testSomething(){
    def dc = new SomeController()
    dc.springSecurityService = [
            encodePassword: 'password',
            reauthenticate: { String u -> true},
            loggedIn: true,
            principal: [username:"Bob"]]
    dc.index() 
    ... assertion....
```

It seems that the user is not getting created and can't get the `principal.id`. Any suggestions or better alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the user is just being created, but not saved, and that's why it doesn't have an ID.

The solution could be this:

```
void testSomething(){
    def dc = new SomeController()
    def loggedInUser = new User(username: "Bob").save() // This way the user will have an ID
    dc.springSecurityService = [
        encodePassword: 'password',
        reauthenticate: { String u -> true},
        loggedIn: true,
        principal: loggedInUser]
    dc.index() ... assertion....
```

There's an alternative:

```
void testSomething(){
    def dc = new SomeController()
    def loggedInUser = new User(...).save()
    dc.metaClass.getLoggedInUser = { loggedInUser }
...
```

I would suggest a refactor to getLoggedInUser:

```
private getLoggedInUser(){
    return springSecurityService.currentUser
}
```

With this change, you could write:

```
void testSomething(){
    def dc = new SomeController()
    def loggedInUser = new User(...).save()
    dc.springSecurityService = [
        encodePassword: 'password',
        reauthenticate: { String u -> true},
        loggedIn: true,
        getCurrenUser: { loggedInUser }]
...
```

Comment: This saves my life!